# C-t 操作でカーソル行をトップ行へ持って行く

Tags: emacs

たまにお世話になっている者です。
emacsで操作です。
私のemacsでの設定で, C-u 0 l
でカーソル行をトップ行にできます。
これはかなり使います、でもこの
「コントロール + u」,「0」「エル」操作
は多く、少しでも順序を間違えると編集して
しまいます。この操作を C-t 「コントロール + t」
したいのですがinit.elの記述で可能でしょうか？
どのたか教えてもらえればと思います。
nagao

Comment: global-binding で良ければ `(global-set-key (kbd "C-t") '(lambda () (interactive) (recenter-top-bottom 0)))` ただし、デフォルトの `C-t(transpose-chars)` が使えなくなります。

Comment: ちなみに、いまのEmacsだとデフォルトで`C-l`が`recenter-top-bottom`に割り当てられているので、`C-l`を2回打つとカーソル行が画面最上行になると思います。

Comment: metropolisさん、emasakaさんどうも有難うございます。
どちらの方法もちゃんとできるようです。
おかげさまで助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

metropolisさんとemasakaさんのコメントで解決できました。ありがとうございます。
global-binding で良ければ

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-t")
    '(lambda () (interactive) (recenter-top-bottom 0)))
```

ただし、デフォルトの <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>(`transpose-chars`) が使えなくなります。

ちなみに、いまのEmacsだとデフォルトでC-lが`recenter-top-bottom`に割り当てられているので、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l‌</kbd>​を2回打つとカーソル行が画面最上行になる‌​と思います。